# Image of a small open disk under $f(z)= \exp (1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

In Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*, the function $f(z)= \exp (1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. But what would the image of a small punctured open disk $\{z:0<|z|< \delta\}$ be under this function? I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: What is the image of that punctured disk under $z \mapsto 1/z$? Given that, and what you know about the exponential function, what is the image under $z\mapsto e^{1/z}$? (Also, if you know it already: Picard's theorem.)

Comment: Well, to your first question isn't it the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}- \{0\}$, under the Möbius transformation of inversion?

Comment: No, $z\mapsto 1/z$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ to itself, so the small punctured disk is mapped to only a subset of the punctured plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z = \epsilon e^{i \theta}$ to be an arbitrary point in the open disk (with $0 < \epsilon < \delta$).  We note that
$$
\exp(1/z) = \exp(\epsilon^{-1} \exp(-i\theta)) = 
\exp(\epsilon^{-1} [\cos \theta - i\sin \theta]) =\\
\exp[\epsilon^{-1}\cos \theta]\exp[-i\epsilon^{-1}\sin \theta]
$$
Now, suppose we have an arbitrary non-zero complex number $z' = re^{i \theta'}$.  Then $z'$ is in the image of the disk if there is a solution to the system
$$
\cos \theta = \epsilon \ln(r)\\
\sin \theta = -\epsilon[\theta' + 2 \pi k]\\
\epsilon < \delta, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
That is, $z'$ will be in the image of the disk as long as we can select an $\epsilon < \delta$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
\epsilon^2\left([\ln(r)]^2 + [\theta' + 2\pi k]^2\right) = 1
$$
From here, it should be clear that every non-zero $z'$ will be in the image.  In particular, we may prove it as follows:

Fix $k > 1/\delta^2$.  It is clear that $\left([\ln(r)]^2 + [\theta' + 2\pi k]^2\right) > 1/\delta^2$.  Define 
$$
f(\epsilon) = \epsilon^2\left([\ln(r)]^2 + [\theta' + 2\pi k]^2\right)
$$
We note that $f(0) = 0 < 1$, and $f(\delta) > 1$.  By the intermediate value theorem, $f(\epsilon) = 1$ has a solution with $\epsilon \in (0,\delta)$.

Comment: But what exactly is the image?

Comment: @Libertron I've showed you that every non-zero complex number is in the image.  Is zero also in the image?

Comment: Nope, every nonzero complex number is in the image as you explained.

Comment: It is correct that every non-zero number **is** in the image, but you need to verify that the the number $0$ **is not** in the image.  Having done so, you will know exactly what the image of the disk is.

Comment: But couldn't I say that by Picard's theorem, the function never attains a value of $0$ even though $0$ is an essential singularity?

Comment: Picard's theorem does **not** tell you that the function never attains zero.  It does tell you that the image will be the entire complex plane except for maybe one point, which may or may not be zero.